# Trouble calling a plugin's controller function from within an event listener function

Tags: plugin-development, events, controller

I am working on extending the [formbuilder2](https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS) plugin to call and pass the $event variable to a custom Controller after FormBuilder2 has initialized the "onBeforeSave" event within the FormBuilder2 Entry_Controller.

**Background Info**

- Trying to extend the Formbuilder2 plugin
- My plugin is called FormBuilder2ExtensionPlugin
- Trying to call a Controller Function from within my FormBuilder2Extension_NotifyController and pass $event variables.
- Within my FormBuilder2Extension_NotifyController, I am calling the actionNotifyAdmin($event) function.

**My Plugin Logic:**

1. FormBuilder2 Plugin saves entry and initializes the "onBeforeSave"
   event.
2. FormBuilder2Extension Plugin listens for "onBeforeSave"
   event, and triggers a custom controller function to run. *Note: Must be
   able to pass the $event variables to the new FormBuilder2Extension
   controller function as well.*
3. FormBuilder2Extension Controller will then parse $event data, and
   run other FormBuilder2 Controller & Service functions using the $data, so I will need to link from FormBuilder2Extension Controller functions to Formuilder2 Controller functions.

**My Problem:**

- Cannot figure out how to run a Controller Function from within the init() event listener and pass the $event variables as well.

**My Current Code: (within main plugin file)**

```
 public function init()
   {
       parent::init();

       craft()->on('formBuilder2_entry.beforeSave', function(Event $event)
       {

         $url = UrlHelper::getActionUrl('formBuilder2Extension/notify/notifyAdmin', array('event' => $event));

         return;
       });
   }
```

**Closing Remarks:**

It works if I use a service function.

Example: `craft()->formBuilder2Extension_notify->notifySubmitterOfSubmission($event);`

But I would rather not rewrite the same Controller & Service functions that formbuilder2 has already written and place it within my service folder.

Any thoughts…? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You really, really shouldn't do this.

I'm not familiar with FormBuilder, but if it is well-built, its controllers will comprise thin methods calling services to do the grunt work; services which you can also call.

If there isn't a service method which does what you want (still assuming everything is well-architected), that means the author chose not to make that functionality part of FormBuilder's API, presumably for a good reason.

If FormBuilder isn't well-built, and instead shoves a load of code in its controllers, well, that's still not a reason for you to do something similarly ill-considered.